# mysql trigger for updating a table after new row in another table

Tags: mysql, wordpress, triggers

I'm currently fooling around with a Wordpress website, and I was wondering if it was possible to create a trigger that updates a wordpress post, to be specific the `post_content` column, after I've inserted a new row in a different table.

Lets say I named this table `persons` , and created four columns `ID`,`post_ID`,`zipCode`, and `name`. The `post_id` is the foreign key to the `wordpress_posts` table.

I've created a post in wordpress where all new entries made in the `persons` table should be displayed. This post has `ID` 1.

What should my update trigger look like to get this to work?

I've tried this, with no luck:

```
BEGIN

   UPDATE wp_posts
   (wp_posts.post_content) WHERE wp_posts.ID = postID;
   VALUES
   (persons.zipCode, persons.name);

END;
```

Error message:

```
#1064 - you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(wp_posts.posts_content) WHERE wp_posts.ID = postID; VALUES (persons.zipC' at line 4
```

Some explanation would very much be appreciated!

Comment: Start with the [right syntax for **`UPDATE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html). That's not even close. Once you've got that we can address the trigger syntax. (Yes, what you want *is* possible.)

Comment: I'm sorry guys... I will admit I still suck at this, but I'm also learning alot every day. I thought I had the syntax at least sort of right, but I guess I took in the wrong information. Thanks for the right syntax @DarwinvonCorax

Comment: Now to your actual question: when you update `wp_posts.post_content` do you want to *replace* the existing value or *append* to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you doesn't have read MySQL reference for UPDATE syntax and you doesn't have seen any examples of a MySQL trigger.
An other problem, is that you trying to update one persons column with two wp_posts columns. You must use string concatenation for this.

Try something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_post_content AFTER INSERT ON persons
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE wp_posts
    SET wp_posts.post_content=CONCAT(NEW.zipCode, NEW.name)
    WHERE wp_posts.ID = NEW.postID;
  END;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a standard audit-trail trigger. Pragmatically, you could use a **`BEFORE`** trigger for this, but conceptually an **`AFTER`** trigger makes more sense. What is necessary, though, is that this be a **`ROW`** trigger, since it's making use of the data being written to the triggering table.

A **`ROW`** trigger should not, and on most databases is not permitted to, query the table to which it is attached, as this can violate the ACID consistency rule. (This is the so-called "mutating table" problem.) Instead, a **`ROW`** trigger has access to the pseudorecords **`OLD`** and **`NEW`** which represent the single row whose modification caused the trigger to fire. **`OLD`** contains the row data *as it was* before the DML statement was issued, and **`NEW`** contains the data *as it will be* after the DML statement commits. You access fields in these records as table-qualified field names, with **`OLD`** or **`NEW`** as the table name eg. `OLD.col1`, `NEW.col2` &c.

In a **`BEFORE ROW`** trigger you can actually modify the content of **`NEW`** and thus change what will be written, but we don't need to do that here.

I'll assume you want to append the new data to the existing post; we do that with the variadic `CONCAT` function. The complete syntax would be

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER log_wp_update
  AFTER INSERT
  ON persons
  FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE wp_posts
      SET post_content = CONCAT(post_content, ' ', NEW.zipCode, ' ', NEW.name)
      WHERE ID = 1;
```

Since the body of this trigger is a simple **`UPDATE`** statement, there's no need to wrap it in `BEGIN ... END;` and no need to use `DELIMITER` directives if your client requires them.

I hope that helps. If you need any clarification, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Sincerely thanks for this explanation, this helps alot! Still trying to wrap my head around the `old.` and `new.` If `old.` is the value the row had when the trigger fired, why not use old instead of new? Or does `old` point to the wp_posts table?

Comment: `OLD` points to the old version of the row in `log_wp_update`. This is an **`UPDATE`** trigger, though, so the row didn't exist before the trigger fired and `OLD` contains **`NULL`**.

Answer (score 0):

This will create the trigger:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER update_wp_posts
  AFTER INSERT
  ON persons
  FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE wp_posts
  SET wp_posts.post_content = ?what_should_be_here? 
  WHERE wp_posts.ID = NEW.post_ID;
```

but I have not clear what you want to put in wp_posts.post_content.

Regards